Problem solving constrainted integer problem with NMaximize
It seems that NMaximize fails to solve an instance of simple integer program. Any help on how to enhance the performance of NMaximize would be greatly appreciated.
(*Parameters*)
r = 5;
xtable = Array[x, r];
v = {2.2399954328076297`, 1.3346233579339735`, 1.3570077790603206`, 
   1.4029487416407995`, 0.9581188075415371`};
t1 = {0.675139521819273`, 0.4813025900695662`, 0.21099368227403703`, 
   0.4196827212420777`, 0.5076190803196177`};
t2 = {0.7086293194873113`, 0.5281315444358912`, 0.23382763522951777`, 
   0.4479953521208542`, 0.593606398656473`};
b = 1.01372`;

(*Optimization problem*)
objective = Sum[v[[j]] x[j], {j, 1, r}]
constraint1 = 
 Flatten[{Sum[x[j]*t1[[j]], {j, 1, r}] <= b, 
   Sum[x[j], {j, 1, r}] <= 5, Table[1 >= x[j] >= 0, {j, 1, r}]}]
constraint2 = 
 Flatten[{Sum[x[j]*t2[[j]], {j, 1, r}] <= b, 
   Sum[x[j], {j, 1, r}] <= 5, Table[1 >= x[j] >= 0, {j, 1, r}]}]

Notice that parameters t2 are strictly higher than t1. Hence, any x that satisfies constraint1 also satisfies constraint2. NMaximize does not result in a correct solution.
(*Maximization*)
output1 = 
 NMaximize[objective, constraint1, xtable \[Element] Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "Automatic"]
output2 = 
 NMaximize[objective, constraint2, xtable \[Element] Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "Automatic"]


Output:
2.24 x[1] + 1.33462 x[2] + 1.35701 x[3] + 1.40295 x[4] + 0.958119 x[5]

{0.67514 x[1] + 0.481303 x[2] + 0.210994 x[3] + 0.419683 x[4] + 
   0.507619 x[5] <= 1.01372, x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] <= 5, 
 1 >= x[1] >= 0, 1 >= x[2] >= 0, 1 >= x[3] >= 0, 1 >= x[4] >= 0, 
 1 >= x[5] >= 0}

{0.708629 x[1] + 0.528132 x[2] + 0.233828 x[3] + 0.447995 x[4] + 
   0.593606 x[5] <= 1.01372, x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] <= 5, 
 1 >= x[1] >= 0, 1 >= x[2] >= 0, 1 >= x[3] >= 0, 1 >= x[4] >= 0, 
 1 >= x[5] >= 0}

{2.75996, {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 1, x[5] -> 0}}

{3.597, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0}}

We can check that both solutions satisfy constraint1 and constraint 2
constraint1 /. output1[[2]]
constraint1 /. output2[[2]]
constraint2 /. output1[[2]]
constraint2 /. output2[[2]]

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

Changing an optimization method is not very helpful
(*Maximization*)
output1 = 
 NMaximize[objective, constraint1, xtable \[Element] Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "NelderMead"]
output2 = 
 NMaximize[objective, constraint2, xtable \[Element] Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "NelderMead"]

constraint1 /. output1[[2]]
constraint1 /. output2[[2]]
constraint2 /. output1[[2]]
constraint2 /. output2[[2]]

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}


Constraints are fullfilled, why do you doubt the result of NMaximize is wrong?

The set of feasible x for constraint2 is strictly smaller than the set of feasible x for constraint1. Hence, the maximum in problem 2 should be weakly smaller than in problem 1. This is not the case.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(*Parameters*)
r = 5;
xtable = Array[x, r];
v = {2.2399954328076297`, 1.3346233579339735`, 1.3570077790603206`, 
   1.4029487416407995`, 0.9581188075415371`};
t1 = {0.675139521819273`, 0.4813025900695662`, 0.21099368227403703`, 
   0.4196827212420777`, 0.5076190803196177`};
t2 = {0.7086293194873113`, 0.5281315444358912`, 0.23382763522951777`, 
   0.4479953521208542`, 0.593606398656473`};
b = 1.01372`;

(*Optimization problem*)

objective = v . xtable;

constraint1 = Flatten[{t1 . xtable <= b, Total@xtable <= 5, 
    Table[1 >= x[j] >= 0, {j, 1, r}]}];
constraint2 = Flatten[{t2 . xtable <= b, Total@xtable <= 5, 
    Table[1 >= x[j] >= 0, {j, 1, r}]}];

(*Maximization*)
output1 = 
 NMaximize[Flatten@{objective, constraint1}, xtable \[Element] Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "Automatic"]

(* {2.75996, {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 1, x[5] -> 0}} *)

NMaximize may return a local maximum rather than a global maximum. Checking,
output1r = {{objective /. #, #}, And @@ constraint1 /. #} & /@
  FindInstance[Flatten@{objective > output1[[1]], constraint1}, xtable, 
   Integers, 5]

(* {{{3.597, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0}}, True}} *)

output2 = 
 NMaximize[Flatten@{objective, constraint2}, xtable \[Element] Integers, 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "Automatic"]

(* {3.597, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0}} *)

Checking,
output2r = {{objective /. #, #}, And @@ constraint2 /. #} & /@
  FindInstance[Flatten@{objective > output2[[1]], constraint2}, xtable, 
   Integers, 5]

(* {} *)

EDIT: Alternate approach
MaximalBy[
  If[And @@ constraint1 /. #, {objective /. #, #}, 
     Nothing] & /@ (Thread[xtable -> #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, r]),
  First][[1]]

(* {3.597, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0}} *)

EDIT 2:
More efficient, particularly for larger r
tuples = Select[Thread[xtable -> #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, r],
  And @@ constraint1 /. # &]; 

MaximalBy[{objective /. #, #} & /@ tuples, First][[1]]

However, this will not get you to r = 30 (1073741824 tuples) in reasonable time

Well, NMaximize is tailored to look for global maxima. Your second approach seems very interesting. Let me try to test it for speed, as I need to solve variants of the problem with r up to 30. I also need to solve these problems quickly.

Thank you for EDIT2! It might get me to r=30 as one of my constraints is the number of 1 should be fewer than 5. Hence, I need to consider only vectors of 0 and 1 with fewer than five ones, which is much smaller than 1 billion.
